# GridBagLayout - GridBagConstraints not working

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to use `GridBagLayout` but the `GridBagConstraints` objects doesn't show any effect. I want a button to fill the horizontal space. Any Ideas?

```
static class Five extends JFrame {

    public Five() {
        setSize(300, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        JButton button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4");

        add(button, c);

        setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: *"Any Ideas?"* Two. 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). For this case that means - add a `main(..)` method end relevant imports. 2) Post a screenshot (or a link to one) of the GUI stretched wider than natural size.

Answer (score 3):

This works, details in comments:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Five extends JFrame {

    public Five() {
        setSize(300, 400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // best to do all important stuff in a panel added to the frame
        JPanel gui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); 
        setContentPane(gui);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1d; // fixes the problem

        JButton button = new JButton("Long-Named Button 4");

        add(button, c);
        pack(); // should always be done after all components are added

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Five();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

### Further tips:

1. There is no good case for extending `JFrame` in this case, just do the relevant additions etc. to an instance of a standard frame.
2. To make the button larger, set a large icon, large insets, or large font. To make the frame bigger, add an `EmptyBorder` around the `gui` panel.